# How to target xxxhdpi devices in Android manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest, hdpi

According to Google documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html#compatible-screens) I am using the `<compatibile screen>` tag to target specific screens for my app (I'm trying to target phones only). This is my manifest :

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />

</compatible-screens>
```

Doing so however, some devices are listed as not compatible in the Google Play Store, for instance the Samsung Galaxy S6, the nexus 5x and the nexus 6P. It seems that all devices with a very high dpi are not included (xxxdpi). How do I include those phones?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I cannot get the S6+, 5X, or nexus 6P to show up on the Play Store.

Comment: Nexus 6P, Galaxy S6,.. are xxhdpi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use can define in manifest file in this manner

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

and for more detail please follow this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: I have been using this, but still the Play Store still blocks out the S6+ edge, Nexus 5X, and Nexus 6P. I did not include values for `requiresSmallestWidthDp`, `compatibleWidthLimitDp`, or `largestWidthLimitDp` because they don't seem to be needed. All of my other parameters are set to `true`.

Comment: To support the S6+, nexus 5x and other similar devices, I have putted only these information in the manifest.Keep in mind that in this way you will support only smartphones and not tablets :                                                               <supports-screens android:resizeable= "false"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="false"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>